# converting bitmap to byte arrays and sending using sockets android

Tags: java, android, arrays, sockets, bitmap

I'm trying to send an image that was taken by my camera in my application as a byte array. I convert the bitmap to byte array, then to Base64 string, then endcode that to a byte array and send. When I try to send it however I get an exception that my string is too long to send.

preparing to send through to socket:

```
        if(currentChatPartner==null)
            return;
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
        msg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, 0);
        sendThroughSocketImage(encoded, clientSocket, currentChatPartner.getIP(), currentChatPartner.getPort());
```

Sending through to socket:

```
        byte[] decoded = null;
        decoded = encoded.getBytes();
        try 
        {
            socket.send(new DatagramPacket(decoded, decoded.length, ip, port));
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.err.println("\nUnable to send message");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
```

Sometimes it works, but most it doesn't :( Is there a reason for this?? Is there a way I could fix it or shorten the string that is to be sent??

Answer (score 0):

By using DatagramPacket you're sending an UDP message that has a miximum length a little short of 64kb. Easy to get a message to long exception. You should send your data using TCP socket.

Plenty of examples online e.g.

http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/

With respect to your comments, an example of sending the byte array via client socket

```
    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
    socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
    int start=0;
    int len=decoded.length;
    OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream(); 
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);
    dos.write(array, start, len);
```

Comment: Is there any way to compress or shorten the string? If not, is it still possible send a bitmap image as a byte array/string through TCP?

Comment: Compression can get you somewhere, still with UDP the restriction on size is to rigid in my opinion, so even with compressing your likely to get a message too long at one point. I provided a snippet for sending byte array, but be alert I've just typed it out, so some if checks and some exception handling should be put in place

Comment: Thank you for the snippet of code. I'm working on 2 hours of sleep at the moment, so will try and mark as answer as soon as I get it working. Dumb question, but I could still encode the string as Base64 as above and send byte[] decoded = null; decoded = encoded.getBytes(); with the code you've given me? This is a great starting point! Thank you!